# shorten the weekdays from texts

Tags: python, regex, datetime, formatting, python-2.7

I am writing a python library that takes a paragrah that consists of different types of hours format. Paragraph is actually taken from different restaurant sites, they have hours of operation in various formats for each site. So, I decided to write a library that takes any format of (eg: M-Fri 10am - 12pm, M, Tue, Wed 00:00-18:00 etc.). My decision is to write different set of RegEx that takes a string and proceeds if it matches any of my pattern.

I have choosen RegEx pattern matching because, instead of writing own logics for every pattern and replacing just using str.replace may takes a lot of time. But I stuck in regex since I am new to it. So any of you can suggest me how can I do the following task?

As a first step I would like to shorten all the weekday formats to 3 letter shorten week days as below.
Example:
"**Monday 09:00 AM - 5:00 PM, Tuesday 09:00 AM - 5:00 PM, Wednesday 09:00 AM - 5:00 PM, Thursday 09:00 AM - 5:00 PM, Friday 09:00 AM - 5:00 PM, Saturday Closed, Sunday Closed**"

Output should be
"**Mon** 09:00 AM - 5:00 PM, **Tue** 09:00 AM - 5:00 PM, **Wed** 09:00 AM - 5:00 PM, **Thu** 09:00 AM - 5:00 PM, **Fri** 09:00 AM - 5:00 PM, **Sat** Closed, **Sun** Closed"

Thanks.

Comment: I tried string.replace but that should be done over and over. I like to have a single regex to replace all of them to the shorten format.

Comment: I'm curious to know - wouldn't using a regex do the same thing you are trying to avoid? Won't it have to be done over and over for each match? If so, using a regex is not the approach you would want to take. It's ugly and can be a pain to maintain. mgilsons answer looks like the best solution.

Comment: @spots thanks, I got solution from MorganBorman

Answer (score 5, accepted):

seems like a simple [`str.replace`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) should work here:

```
new_paragraph = paragraph.replace('Monday','Mon')
```

You can even use the [`calendar`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/calendar.html#calendar.day_name) module to make this a little easier:

```
import calendar

for day,abbr in zip(calendar.day_name,calendar.day_abbr):
    paragraph = paragraph.replace(day,abbr)
```

---

for *really* big paragraphs, it might be worthwhile to switch over to regex:

```
import re
import calendar

regex = re.compile('|'.join(calendar.day_name))
sub_dict = dict(zip(calendar.day_name,calendar.day_abbr))
new_paragraph = regex.sub(lambda match: sub_dict[match.group(0)],paragraph)
```

Of course, with calendar, the abbreviations/etc are locale dependent (but maybe that's desirable anyway)

Comment: Needs to be 

paragraph = paragraph.replace(day, abbr)

Comment: @MorganBorman -- Thanks.  Brain flop.

Comment: I used re.sub with ignore case, so that I can replace without minding about the day should be capitalized. "Monday" => "Mon" but "monday" wont result "Mon". So, re.sub is better than replace

Answer (score 0):

Try with this pattern : ([a-zA-Z]{3})[a-zA-Z]+( [0-9]| Closed)
and this replacement  : $1$2